# Core dump with scanf()

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, scanf, coredump

I'm getting a coredump with the following scanf() implementation.  I've tried using malloc to allocate the memory used to read this string but that did not fix the issue either.  How can I read a string from scanf() without causing a core dump?

```
char take[150];
scanf("%149s", take);
```

Comment: I've also tried with scanf("%s", take);  I get the same result

Comment: How certain are you that this is where the bug is? You do not check the return code, so you don't know if the read was successful, but otherwise there is nothing in this meagre code sample that should cause a segfault. Have you considered using `std::string` and `std::cin`?